# 2 pictures filling full width with the same height

Tags: css

Bonjour,

I have 2 pictures and I would like to display those side by side.
I would want them to fill the whole width of the container and to have the same height.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it?
I'd want to preserve image ratio.
The green frame represent my container (probably some *div*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'whole width' = 100% of user's screen? Or, some fixed width?

Comment: @nevermind : 100% width of the container

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-height` and give the value to it - the minimum value of height compared to both the images `max-height: minimum-image-height(from both images)`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.image {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" class="image" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="" class="image" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's insanely simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Madlozoz Its my pleasure!

Comment: But with major shortcoming: The width do not ajust

Comment: @Madlozoz If you adjust the width the image will stretch, and I don't think that you are going to do that. Also if this helped you out you can accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the codepen and snippet using flex:(http://codepen.io/dpes/pen/MbeBbd)

```css
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.flex-container img {
    object-fit: contain;
     max-height: 300px;
     min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/500/">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/400/">
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the code. Now, any resolution images  images take same size and heightand maintain aspect ratio.